# How to restrict bypassing bash ssh tunnel

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh

I am using SSH to exchange some keys between my server and a client.

Here the client should use SSH to send me his public key; my question is, how to restrict the other commands in bash?

Even if I use `rbash`, the client can run commands like:

```
ssh remote_host command_to_run
```

What can I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: Can you please clarify what "the other commands bash" means? Also please show us how you are making the key exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to authorize only one command on the server when a particular SSH key is used ? If yes, you can check the `command` statement of the `authorized_keys` file.

For example to authorize only `ps -aux` when the user foobar use KEY, you can edit `/home/foobar/.ssh/authorized_keys` this way :

`command="ps -aux" ssh-rsa KEY`

See the [manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8?query=sshd).

Comment: i didn't find a command in my config file

Comment: You can add it. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at sshd_config on your (server) machine.
"Match" and "ForceCommand" should provide you with means for 
restricting the commands available (or which command(s) to execute on connect).

You might also consider allowing only scp (to a specific directory)
and pickup the files from a daemon (or cron job) on the server.

Comment: could you explain more please